# Office365 move 1 email from 1 folder, to another, via powershell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to know if it is possible to move 1 email fra 1 folder to another folder on the same email, with powershell using emailID ?

Cant really find anything about moving 1 email to another place, only thing i can find is move by subject.

Hope anyone can help me.

Have a really nice day :)

The code i got so far

move by subject:

```
$SourceUserName="name"; 
$TargetUserName="name"; 
$TargetFolderName="foldername"; 
$SubjectName ="subject name"; 
Search-Mailbox $SourceUserName -SearchQuery "$SubjectName" -TargetMailbox "$TargetUserName" -TargetFolder "$TargetFolderName" -DeleteContent -Confirm:$false
```

Move by Bulk, a whole email

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
$O365CREDS = Get-Credential
$ONPREMCREDS = Get-Credential
$SESSION = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $O365CREDS -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $SESSION
Connect-MsolService -Credential $O365CREDS
$MAILBOXLIST = Import-CSV "C:\list.csv"
foreach ($line in $MAILBOXLIST) {New-MoveRequest -Identity $line.alias -Remote -RemoteHostName hybridserver.domainname.com -TargetDeliveryDomain domainname.mail.onmicrosoft.com -RemoteCredential $ONPREMCREDS -BadItemLimit 1000}
Get-MoveRequest | Get-MoveRequestStatistics
Get-MoveRequest | Remove-MoveRequest
```

But none of the codes can move 1 email to a folder.

Comment: Please post the code that you used to move an email by subject and perhaps we can assist in modifying it.

Comment: please put code in your question instead of in the comments.

Comment: I have done that now, moved it into my question

Comment: What does the second code do? Move all the emails listed in the CSV folder? You just need to change that to work on one email.

Comment: the secound code lets you login to your office365 account via powershell, then looks into the CSV file and moves the once listet.

Comment: So first.... put the one email that you want to move in your CSV. Does that do what you want? Now do some research on the `Search-Mailbox` cmdlet to see if you can identify the email you want to move