# Powershell script, load from CSV?

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

So i got this code:

```
$MailboxName = "email@domain.com"
$MessageId = "<54bb33d72d7ed2b1928e9fb9edfa0ca2@swift.generated>"
$TargetFolder = "\Inbox\random"
Connect-EXRMailbox -MailboxName $MailboxName
Find-EXRMessageFromMessageId -MailboxName $MailboxName -MessageId $MessageId | ForEach-Object{
    Move-EXRMessage -MailboxName $MailboxName -ItemURI $_.ItemRESTURI -TargetFolderPath $TargetFolder
    Write-Host ("Moved Message " + $_.Subject + " to " + $TargetFolder)
}
```

It works fine, and will move that one email who fits the messageID

But im now trying to make it so it looks at a .csv file insted of 1 file. In the csv file there is alot of messageIDs.

If i use this code:

```
import-csv d:\test.csv | Select MessageId 
$MailboxName = "email@domain.com"
$MessageId = $_.MessageId 
$TargetFolder = "\indbakke\Hotels" 
Connect-EXRMailbox -MailboxName $MailboxName
Find-EXRMessageFromMessageId -MailboxName $MailboxName -MessageId $MessageId | ForEach-Object{
    Move-EXRMessage -MailboxName $MailboxName -ItemURI $_.ItemRESTURI -TargetFolderPath $TargetFolder
    Write-Host ("Moved Message " + $_.Subject + " to " + $TargetFolder)
}
```

Then it will just print whats in the .csv file,

Can anyone help me out, how do i get my small script working with a CSV file, so it takes messageID from the csv file. ?

Comment: Isn't that what your other question does? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498058/office365-move-1-email-from-1-folder-to-another-via-powershell

Comment: No its a new script. 

But lets say i set "$messageID = Import-csv "d:\test.csv"

 I get the following error: 


Find-EXRMessageFromMessageId : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'MessageId'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.
At line:5 char:67
+ ... FromMessageId -MailboxName $MailboxName -MessageId $MessageId | ForEa ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over `messageId`s from imported csv. In your code, you just import the file, and that's it. `$MessageId` is empty.

```
$messageIds = Import-Csv -Path d:\test.csv |
    Select -expandproperty MessageId

ForEach ($MessageId in $messageIds)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Hi Petr. thanks alot, it help.! It moved the files now.

But it asked me to connect to my mailbox 3 times, do you know if i get it to do it once?

Comment: Make sure Connect-EXRMailbox -MailboxName $MailboxName is outside of the ForEach Loop you only need this once to authenticate